# python regex parse string with brackets

Tags: python, python-re

I would like to parse a string with or without brackets.  Basically for `john[doe]`, I would like to get two variables, basically outside the `[]` and inside the bracket.  So for this example I would like to extract `john` and `doe`.  The string will always have this structure.  But another example can also be just `john`, means second variable is `""` or `None`.  How can I do this using the re library? Or just straight Python, if it's more efficient that regex?

This is what I tried so far:

```
s = sample_string.split("[")
x, y = (sample_string, None) if len(s) == 1 else (s[0], s[1][:-1])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can there be nested brackets? Are brackets always matching?

Comment: I was originally using split with '[' then remove ']' from the second one, if there is a second element.  No nested brackets.  Just XXX[YYY] or XXXX format really

Comment: This can be done with regular expressions which is also efficient.

Comment: And there is nothing else in the string?

Comment: Nope, if its not in that format, can just say its invalid string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex solution:

```
r'^([^[]+)(?:\[([^\]]+)])?$'
```

1. `^` Matches start of string.
2. `([^[]+)` Capture group 1: matches 1 or more characters that are not '['.
3. `(?:` Start of non-capturing group.
4. `\[` Matches '['.
5. `([^\]]+)` Capture group 2: matches 1 or more characters that are not ']'.
6. `]` Matches ']'
7. `)` End of non-capturing group.
8. '?' The non-capturing group is optional.

```
import re

tests = ['john', 'john[doe]']

for test in tests:
    m = re.match(r'^([^[]+)(?:\[([^\]]+)])?$', test)
    if m:
        print(test, '->', m[1], m[2])
```

Prints:

```
john -> john None
john[doe] -> john doe
```

**Explanations**

First, anything between parentheses `(    )` is a capturing group. Anything between `(?:  )` is a non-capturing group. Either of these types of groups can contain capturing an non-capturing groups within. `[]` is used to define a set of characters. For example, `[aqw]` matches 'a', 'q' or 'w'. `[a-e]` matches 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' or 'e'. `[^aqw]` with a leading `^` negates the set meaning it matches any character other than 'a', 'q', 'w'. So, `[^\]]` matches any character other than ']' (you have to put a `\` character in front of the `]` character to "escape" it because in that context `]` has special meaning (it would otherwise close the `[]` construct). The following `+` sign denotes "one or more of what preceded this". So `([^[]+)` matches one or more of nay character that is not a `[`.

I hope the preceding explanations help.

Comment: Sorry, can you break down steps 2 and 5? How those are capturing those groups

Comment: I've added some explanations. I have to run now for a while. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement that you use regex for this? It's probably easier without:

```
if '[' in string:
  x, y = string.split('[')
  y = y.strip(']')
else:
  x, y = string, ''
```

Something to include regex might look like this:

```
if '[' in string:
  x, y = re.findall('^(.+)\[(.+)?]', string)[0]
else:
  x, y = string, ''
```

Comment: It is not a requirement to use regex, was just thinking that will be more efficient.  Especially if its done many many times.  I basically did something like that without looking for '[' and just splitting right away.  I'll update my question with it

Answer (score 0):

As long as `john[doe]` is a string type, you should be able to parse the phrase using the `replace` function:

```
import re

x = str('john[doe]')
new_x = x.replace("[", " ").replace("]", "")
print(new_x)
```

or, if you want to, you can use the `match` function:

```
import re

x = str('john[doe]')
m = re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+)\[(?P<last_name>\w+)\]", x)
name = m.group('first_name') + " " + m.group('last_name')
print(name)
```

Without having more phrases to parse, I am not sure which of the two is faster. Good luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

There are probably better ways to do it but this worked for me.

```
s = "john[doe]"
arr = []
x = re.split("\[", s)[1]
arr.append(re.split("\[", s)[0])
arr.append(re.split("\]", x)[0])
print(arr)
```